# Installing serverless on ubuntu 20 using npm gives an error

Tags: npm, serverless

Installing **serverless** on **ubuntu 20**, using **npm**. Its throwing an error as:

```
npm WARN deprecated @types/chalk@2.2.0: This is a stub types definition for chalk (https://github.com/chalk/chalk). chalk provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/chalk installed!
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/lib/node_modules
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/serverless/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```